# Sabre Hotel Content Rest API stopped working

Tags: sabre

POSTing to https://api.sabre.com/v1.0.0/shop/hotels/content?mode=content yesterday worked fine, but with the same Postman request is failing today.

The fault code is: "`Client.InvalidCustomerAppId`" (but the Http status code is 200.)

Nothing changed on our end, is it possible that I was using an account that no longer has access to this API?

Full JSON response is:

```
{
  "Fault": {
    "faultcode": "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Client.InvalidCustomerAppId",
    "faultstring": "Field CustomerAppId is invalid",
    "detail": {
      "StackTrace": [
        "com.sabre.universalservices.base.exception.ApplicationException: errors.xml.USG_INVALID_CUSTOMER_APP_ID"
      ]
    }
  },
  "Links": [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "https://api.sabre.com/v1.0.0/shop/hotels/content?mode=content"
    },
    {
      "rel": "linkTemplate",
      "href": "https://api.sabre.com/<version>/shop/hotels/content?mode=<mode>"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to the PROD environment? Perhaps you were testing on api.test.sabre.com before.

Comment: Nah was always on the PROD environment, nothing changed in the request. Don't worry I think we are discussing with our Sabre contact. Will update when we have a response.

Comment: Still no response from sabre contact yet but it started working again today!